# Lightning Field Labels displayed Inline for some Users

Tags: lightning, fields, label

In our Production Org the Field Labels on Standard and Custom Lighting Pages are displaying "inline" (to the left) instead of above for some Users.
I know you can apply the label-inline variant to lightning-input fields.  However I do not see why the label location would differ between Users.  Also in Sandbox this is working as expected for all Users.
I confirmed the Permissions, Profile and settings are the same for my test Users.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be due to the Comy vs Compact setting that is set per user.

[image]

Comment: THANKS!  I was looking through Permissions and Users settings, but the solution was literally right in front of me!

Comment: Looks like you can set an attribute in the lightning-record-edit-form  to override the User setting 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_display_density